# Send file using POST from a Python script to a PHP Script

Tags: php, python, image, post

```
import urllib,MultipartPostHandler,urllib2,cookielib
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener =     urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies),MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
login = urllib.urlencode(dict(admin_user='admin',admin_pass='****'))
o=opener.open('http://some_domain_name/admin/index.php',login)
print o.read()
### successfully logged-into the system ###################
```

With the help of above code I am able to log into admin panel. Here I am supposed to post some ads (Here I am automating the tasks and the fields covering ad-title, ad-desc, and mainly importantly series of images (list of images would be a better term I guess ;))

HTML Code snippet:

```
<form action="postad.php?cityid=15&subcatid=1" method="post" name="frmPost" enctype="multipart/form-data" 

 <!-- Some other code -->


<td><input name="showemail" type="radio" value="1" >&nbsp;</td>
<table class="postad" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">

<tr>
    <td><b>Upload Pictures:</b><br>
    <span class="hint">Maximum filesize: 300KB</span><br>
                <input type="file" name="pic[]" size="69"><br>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" height="2"><br>
                <input type="file" name="pic[]" size="69"><br>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" height="2"><br>
                <input type="file" name="pic[]" size="69"><br>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" height="2"><br>
                <input type="file" name="pic[]" size="69"><br>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" height="2"><br>
                <input type="file" name="pic[]" size="69"><br>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" height="2"><br>
            </td>
</tr>

</table>


<!-- some other code -->
<input name="do" type="hidden" id="do" value="post">
<button type="submit">Post Now</button>
```

So tackle this I am using this code, but Every time I am failing to attach images. Would you guys help me in this regard.

```
raw_params={"adtitle":"sample title",
        "area":"sample area",
        "addesc":"<p>sample post</p>",
        "price":"2000",
        "x[1]":"2012",
        "email":"abc@def.com",
        "showemail":"2",
        "subcatid":"15",
    "do":"post",
        }

encoded_params=urllib.urlencode(raw_params)
target_page = 'http://some_domain_name/admin/postad.php?cityid=15&subcatid=15'
opener.open(target_page,encoded_params)
```

I forget to tell you one thing this is the log I got from LIVEHTTPHeader (mozilla-plugin)

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="adtitle"

sample title
-----------------------------20165274802361271281051822614
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="area"

sample location
-----------------------------20165274802361271281051822614
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="addesc"

<p>sample post</p>
-----------------------------20165274802361271281051822614
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price"

200
-----------------------------20165274802361271281051822614
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x[1]"

2012
-----------------------------20165274802361271281051822614
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

abc@def.com
-----------------------------20165274802361271281051822614
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="showemail"

2
-----------------------------20165274802361271281051822614
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pic[]"; filename="3_d_flower.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà
```

And please through some light on this:
    filename="3_d_flower.jpg

Comment: I want to know how we can add images to the post request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely recommend the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) library for this. It makes multi-part POSTs [much simpler](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). It also [handles cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) much more simply.

The login code would look like this in requests:

```
import requests
o = requests.get('http://some_domain_name/admin/index.php', 
                 data={admin_user: 'admin',
                       admin_pass: '****'})
print o.text
print o.cookies
```

Comment: I tried this, but its giving me the same login page. Its not working in my case. :( . Is there any possibility that without using any external libraries, I can add files.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but getting requests installed and using it will be far far easier than trying to figure out all of the standard library magic.

Comment: Also, I misread the original code, and now the code I've written shows how to send form data with the request instead of setting auth headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib,MultipartPostHandler,urllib2,cookielib

cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies),MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
login = urllib.urlencode(dict(admin_user='admin',admin_pass='****'))
o=opener.open('http://some_domain_name.com/admin/index.php',login)
print o.read()
### logged-into the system ###################
### Now post the things ####################
raw_params={"adtitle":"sample title",
        "area":"sample area",
        "addesc":"<p>sample post</p>",
        "price":"2000",
        "x[1]":"2012",
        "email":"abc@def.com",
        "showemail":"2",
    "pic[0]":open("indian_eye.jpg", "rb"),
    "pic[1]":open("nature.jpg", "rb"),
        "subcatid":"1",
    "do":"post",
        }




url="http://some_domain_name.com/admin/postad.php?cityid=15&subcatid=1"
opener.open(url, raw_params)

------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: No Fuss, just an easy answer. I Wonder How could I miss that.